# how to split a string of data extracted from the firebase cloud firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I started learning about Firebase Firestore along with Python. I learned how to write data into Firestore and also how to read it. When I am extracting the data from Firestore, the data gets printed on the terminal in the form of a dictionary, something like this:

`{'name': 'Kevin, 'age': '16'}`

But since I am using this data for another project in which separate data is on separate lines, can someone help me to sort out the problem. In the example, I want `'name' : 'Kevin'` to be one line and `'age' : '16'` to be on the next line. Can someone guide me on how to split this dictionary? Or are there other forms of retrieving data from Firestore other than the dictionary form.

All I want is that the data should be printed in two different lines. Someone please help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but the data looks like it is in JSON format. You can use the `json` built-in module to parse the string as a dictionary, and then iterate over the keys in the dictionary. `replace(',', '\n')` might also work but feels a bit less sophisticated.

Comment: can you attach or pins some links so that I can surf on it

Comment: You know how to look things up, right? [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org) has all the information you need, and maybe check the firebase documentation for if the output is indeed json